# Fluent NHibernate - Castle - godaddy - medium trust

Tags: security, nhibernate

I have an issue 'assembly does not allow partially trusted callers' when deploying my local test app to shared web hosting(godaddy).

I have read various posts and solutions and the one that requires least changes to my app appears to be [here](http://iamdotnetcrazy.blogspot.com/2010/09/how-to-get-fluent-nhibernate-nhibernate.html?showComment=1291086816617#c1146478645767384493).

Is there any precompiled dll now available that I could use without rebuilding nhibernate as I dont have access to svn or know exactly how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using NH 3.2 although if you are using Fluent NH then I can't be sure.

There is a [package on NUGET](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/NHibernate.DependencyInjection) that has been created to cater for medium trust environments.
There is also a [blog post](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/NHibernate.DependencyInjection) describing how to use this package.

Basically do a package install:-

> PM> Install-Package NHibernate.DependencyInjection

Then use the following code:-

```
protected void Application_Start() {
  Initializer.RegisterBytecodeProvider();
  ...
  Rest of configuration code here
}
```

You don't need to recompile anything.

Comment: doesn't help:

[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   NHibernate.DependencyInjection.BytecodeProvider..ctor() +40
   NHibernate.DependencyInjection.Initializer.RegisterBytecodeProvider() +40
   ....Application_Start() in Global.asax.cs:59

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to solve it using NHibernate.DependencyInjection.

These were the steps I took:

1) Installed the [NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/NHibernate.DependencyInjection);

2) Implemented IEntityInjector interface:

```
public class EntityInjector : IEntityInjector
{
    public object[] GetConstructorParameters(System.Type type)
    {
        //return null if your objects have parameterless constructors
        return null;
    }
}
```

3) In the Global.asax Application_Start, I registered the injector:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Initializer.RegisterBytecodeProvider(new EntityInjector());

    ...
}
```

I hope this helps.